# Azure Synapse Link for Dataverse not creating folder "OptionsetMetadata" with Power Apps

Tags: azure-synapse, azure-managed-identity

I have created the following Azure Synapse Link for Dataverse:

[image]

According to Microsoft documentation, after creating an Azure Synapse Link, the following five tables are created in a folder named OptionsetMetadata in Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/data-platform/azure-synapse-link-choice-labels

[image]

However, the tables aren't created in our Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2:

Can someone let me know where I might be going wrong?

Comment: Can I get some help with this one please....

Comment: I believe this issue centres around Permissions and Managed Identity, but I'm struggling to find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to create a new Link and see if the tables are created. In our case there is no further setting required. The Folder **OptionsetMetadata** is created automatically in the lake and each of the files is visible a as a table in our Serverless Pool.